# Is there anyway to format my EndPoint URL in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have wrote an endpoint in WordPress and it works just fine. The problem is with the URL. The current format of the URL request must be like this:

https://iotkidsiq.com/wp-json/zaindob/v1/sync_order/key=011900/msisdn=019009

However, The URL request must be in this format:

https://iotkidsiq.com/wp-json/zaindob/v1/sync_order?key=011900&msisdn=019009

How to format that?

```php
register_rest_route( 'zaindob/v1', '/sync_order/' . 'key=' . '(?P<key>\d+)' .  '/msisdn=' . '(?P<msisdn>\d+)' , array( 

    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'updatetable',
  ) );
} );
```

Comment: I removed your links, since they were dead.

Comment: @Danilo you cant remove the links. They are an API URLs. which not viewable for public. I just want to show the format that I aiming to create.